# Blocking IIS rewrite by IP address

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have been using Win Server 2008 running IIS 7 as a reverse proxy server which allows me to have multiple web servers behind a single public IP address.  I have configured IIS 7 with rewrite rules for each of the web servers like this:

`{HTTP_HOST}  Matches the pattern (domain_A.com) Rewrite http://<Server #1 IP>/{R:1}`

Surprisingly, this works.

I'd like to employ IIS ipSecurity to create deny rules that block the rewrite rules for various IP addresses (a poor man's firewall).  I tried adding deny rules to the ipSecurity section of applicationHost.config like this:

`<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true"> <add ipAddress="1.0.0.0" subnetMask="8" allowed="false" /> </ipSecurity>`

The rewrite rules are still triggering for my denied IP addresses, so I suspect that IIS is processing rewrite before ipSecurity.

Is there a way to configure IIS rewrite so that it obeys the deny rules in ipSecurity?

Comment: There is no need to suspect, as that's an obvious thing. You shouldn't use IIS's IP filtering either, but use a firewall in front for that, as even Windows Firewall provides better control on what/how to filter out. Don't attempt to reorder URL Rewrite and IP Security IIS modules as changing such default configuration can give you more nightmares.

Comment: @LexLi - your suggestion makes sense.  Do you know how I can easily edit the "blocked IP" list for Windows Firewall?  Is there a mechanism similar to editing IIS's applicationHost.config file that allows me to add blocked CIDRs analogous to applicationHost.config's ipAddress / subnetMask?  Thank you.

Comment: @LexLi I found several solutions that suggest using `netsh` command in a batch loop to read the blocked IP ranges from a list.  Not exactly the simple solution for which I was searching, but I could make that work.  If you have any suggestions that permit directly editing a list for easy addition, removal and replacement of Windows Firewall rules, that would be ideal.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a condition to the rule that retrieves the host header value by reading the server variable {HTTP_HOST}, matches it against the pattern "domain_A.com", and then negates the result of matching.

```
<rule name="Fail bad requests">
  <match url=".*"/>
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain_A.com" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="AbortRequest" />
</rule>
```

More information you can refer to this link: [Creating an access block rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module#creating-an-access-block-rule).

Comment: samwu - thank you for the suggestion.  I am trying to block incoming requests based on their source IP address.  I think that Lex Li's suggestion to use Windows Firewall (see comment to my original post) makes sense.  Thank you again.